# Cannot export table after changing datasource if table has already been exported

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table-exporter

I'm having some problems troubleshooting what the cause of my issue with mat-table-exporter might be; and am looking for guidance on how to troubleshoot this since I have no console.log output to work with when this issue occurs.

I have what I imagine must be quite a common pattern for loading data into a table and replacing dataSource; here is some sample of the code in question:-

```
The TypeScript
// I have radio buttons on a page to select a different report...
this.regionReportService.getRegionReport(this.reportType, this.regionName, this.regionStats[this.selectedReportNumber].reportId);


// I have a subscription to replace mat-table data when a different report is selected - it's set up in ngOnInit

this.getRegionReportItemsSub = this.regionReportService.getRegionReportListener().subscribe(result => {      
  this.dataSource.data = result;
  this.setAdminReviewedOptions();
  this.reportDisplay = "normal";
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.isLoadingReport = false;
})


this.regionReportService.getRegionReport(this.reportType, this.regionName, this.regionStats[0].reportId);
```

And the HTML...

```
// On the component HTML, I have a button to export the table to Excel
<button style="margin-right: 20px" [disabled]="isChangingEntry || isLoadingReport" 
mat-raised-button (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:  makeFileName(),
sheet: 'sheet 1', Props: {Author: 'Portal'}})"><mat-icon>download</mat-icon>Export to Excel</button>



// The table begins...
 <mat-table matTableExporter [dataSource]="dataSource"
                [ngStyle]="{'display' : isLoadingReport ? 'none' : ''}"
                #exporter="matTableExporter"
                (exportStarted)="isExporting = true"
                (exportCompleted)="isExporting = false"
                matSort matSortActive="itemPrims" matSortDirection="desc" ....
```

And here is the problematic scenario:-

- Works: If I export to Excel when the initial report loads, that works fine; and isExporting is true whilst it's exporting.
- Works: If I select a different report (radio button), so this.dataSource is replaced; that works fine too.
- Doesn't work: If export a report; then I select a different report (radio button) - I'm not able to use the export feature again. When I click 'Export to Excel', isExporting is set to 'true' but nothing else happens, it never goes back to false, and there is no console.log output indicating any error; so it's difficult to troubleshoot.

I wish there was some error; but maybe there is something missing I've not been able to find thus far by googling... like needing to refresh something after changing this.dataSource.data (though, the table displays the new data fine - and the new data is exportable too, just so long as I've not exported something else first...)

Hope that makes sense!

Glen

*Versions: "mat-table-exporter": "^1.2.5", "@angular/core": "~8.2.14", "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3", "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",*

Solution: removing *ngIf on mat-paginator

Answer (score 1):

After trying a a lot of things including upgrading the project from Angular 8 to 9, discovered the following...

The paginator had an *ngIf on it which meant it wasn't visible when the report was loading. It was this that broke mat-table-exporter. Removing the *ngIf resolved the issue.

This:-

```
<mat-paginator *ngIf="!isLoadingReport" #paginator [pageSize]="[100]" [pageSizeOptions]="[100, 500, 1000, 5000]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Has been changed to:-

```
<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="[100]" [pageSizeOptions]="[100, 500, 1000, 5000]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is because your `mat-table matTableExporter` is not detecting the change since you are updating the **data** attribute of your **dataSource** object.

Since the reference doesn't change, just an attribute Angular doesn't detect the change.

You can try something like this, in the example we reasign the object data source in order to make a detection.

```
 this.getRegionReportItemsSub = this.regionReportService.getRegionReportListener().subscribe(result => {      
  this.dataSource= { 
     ...this.dataSource,
     data = result
  };
  this.setAdminReviewedOptions();
  this.reportDisplay = "normal";
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.isLoadingReport = false;
})
```

Other approach is using **ngZone** to trigger the change detector manually, for further information about this check the following link [NgZone](https://angular.io/guide/zone)

Comment: Thanks Diego. It looks like trying to set dataSource like that causes the IDE to complain of missing properties - though explicitly created a new one like this:-

`
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<RegionReportItem>();
this.dataSource = result;
`

results in the same issue. I'll explore your NgZone suggestion - thank you.